# How to control indent of ternary operator using clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

How do I control the indent of ternary operator in clang-format? I want to have ordinary continuation inedent, e.g.

```
int foobar = bar ? a
        : b;
```

Instead I get alignment of operators

```
int foobar = bar ? a
                 : b;
```

I already have AlignOperands: false
Any ideas?

(full options: -style='{BasedOnStyle: LLVM, TabWidth: 4, IndentWidth: 4, ContinuationIndentWidth: 8, UseTab: Always, AlignAfterOpenBracket: false, BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All, AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true, AlignOperands: false, ColumnLimit: 120}')

Comment: Did you found anything? 5 years laters and still having this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe https://reviews.llvm.org/D50078 would resolve this if merged.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest this piece of code if you want to go fancy.

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
bool flag = true;

int c =  \
     flag ? 
         a \
        : b;\

std::cout << c << "\n";
```

Or you can go this way, your choice:

When multiple ternary operators are chained, e.g. like an if/else-if/
else-if/.../else sequence, clang-format will keep aligning the colon
with the question mark, which increases the indent for each
conditionals:

```
int a = condition1 ? result1
                   : condition2 ? result2
                                : condition3 ? result3
                                             : result4;
```

This patch detects the situation (e.g. conditionals used in false branch
of another conditional), to avoid indenting in that case:

```
int a = condition1 ? result1
      : condition2 ? result2
      : condition3 ? result3
                   : result4;
```

When BreakBeforeTernaryOperators is false, this will format like this:

```
int a = condition1 ? result1 :
        condition2 ? result2 :
        conditino3 ? result3 :
                     result4;
```

Comment: Neither of those answers OP's question OP (and I) want:
> I want to have ordinary continuation inedent, e.g.

i.e. no fancy formatting, just, new line = one tab